# Compact Self Adjoint operator on a Hilbert Space

Tags: hilbert-spaces, operator-theory

Let $T$ be a continuous and bounded self-adjoint compact operator on a Hilbert space H.

I want to prove that if $T^2=0$, then $T=0$.

---

Is there any thing wrong with the following:

$T^2$ = $TT^*=0$   impiles that all of T's eigenvalues are zero, and so as T is a compact operator and therefore has finite rank, all of T's eigenvalues are zero, and so $T=0$.

Comment: Compact operators need not have finite rank. They only need to be the limit of finite rank operators in the operator norm.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your proof is not quite right; compact operators need not have finite rank.  The idea does work: a compact self-adjoint operator has an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors (this is the spectral theorem), so if all its eigenvalues are zero, it must be the zero operator.

However, there is a much simpler argument that doesn't need the spectral theorem: for any vector $x$, note that $\| Tx \|^2 = \langle Tx, Tx \rangle$.  Now use the fact that $T=T^*$...

Comment: Somewhat tangentially, naively it seems to me that in any normed space, a continuous operator satisfying $T^2=0$ should have $T=0.$ Can you give me a counterexample? I haven't been able to think of one.

Comment: @RagibZaman: $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$

Comment: Ahh, *very* naively then =). Thanks Nate!